# Is there a concept of embedding degree for non-pairing based elliptic curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field, pairings

From this [post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37302/elliptic-curve-and-embedding-degree/48656#48656), I learned the concept of embedding degree. Intuitively, if embedding degree of an elliptic curve $E(F_p)$ is $k$, it means there is a way to transform points in $E(F_p)$ to $F_{p^k}$. Is the concept of embedding degree only valid for pairing-based elliptic curves, or does the same hold even for non-pairing based elliptic curves?

Comment: *Every* elliptic curve admits [a pairing](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_pairing), and hence the embedding degree makes sense. "Pairing-friendly" means that the embedding degree is particularly small and therefore the pairing can be computed efficiently, but the Weil pairing itself exists for all curves.

Comment: @yyyyyyy I heard that there are 3 types of pairings: weil, tate and ate pairings. So, do all 3 pairings exist on every elliptic curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @yyyyyyy, every curve does have an embedding degree, i.e., there is some $k$ for which $p^k - 1$ is a multiple of $r$, the order one of the subgroups of a curve defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

There is a relevant result from [Koblitz and Balasubramanian](https://doi.org/10.1007/s001459900040) that establishes that the probability that the embedding degree of a random $n$-bit curve of prime order is "small" is vanishingly low:
$$
\mathbf{Pr}[l \mid p^k - 1 \text{ and } k \le (\log p)^2] \le c_3 \frac{(\log 2^n)^9(\log \log 2^n)^2}{2^n} \,.
$$
As such, only "special" curves that are explicitly designed to have small embedding degree $k$, i.e., pairing-friendly curves, are effectively computable; but the pairing does exist for all of them.

Comment: What does it mean to say n-bit curve? If the elliptic curve is of the form $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$, do you mean $a, b$ are randomly sampled $n$-bit values?

Comment: I mean that $p$ is an $n$-bit value, and $a$ and $b$ are sampled from $[0, p-1]$.