# Do Weil, Tate, and Ate pairings exist on all elliptic curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings

I don't know much about the math behind elliptic curves. 
Do [Weil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_pairing), [Tate](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/ep/tate.html) and [Ate pairings](https://www.math.lsu.edu/doc/magma/html/text1285.htm) exist on all elliptic curves? If the answer is negative, then what pairings do MNT, BN and SS curves have?

When we say that an elliptic curve has an [embedding degree](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37302/elliptic-curve-and-embedding-degree) of $k$, do all these pairings map $E(GF(p))$ to $GF(p^k)$? Furthermore, when we speak of embedding degree, are we assuming a specific pairing?

Which of the Weil, Tate and Ate pairings is more efficient? Are there any security trade-offs between these pairings?

Comment: comparing efficiency of various pairings on elliptic curves is not always easy. This recent taxonomy paper might contain some insights: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/485

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In fact, you can write the Weil and Ate pairings in terms of the Tate pairing.

Let $E$ be a curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$ of embedding degree $k$ and prime order $r$. The Weil pairing is related to the Tate pairing as
$$
e(P,Q)^\frac{p^k - 1}{r} = \frac{t(P, Q)}{t(Q, P)}\,,
$$
where $t(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the Tate pairing. Likewise, we have
$$
a(Q, P)^{kp^{k-1} } = t(P, Q)^\frac{((t-1)^k - 1)}{r}\,,
$$
where $a$ is the [Ate pairing](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/110), and $t$ is the trace of Frobenius, i.e., $t = p + 1 - \#E$.

So for all common pairing-friendly curves, all of these pairings exist and are well-defined. The [optimal Ate pairing](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/096) is the most common, since it involves the shortest Miller loop and is often the fastest. But this is not necessarily the case, depending on field sizes, available parallelism, etc.

Comment: That's a great response! What is Miller group?

Comment: Is optimal ate pairing the one that is implemented in all the pairing libraries like PBC, Relic and Miracl?

Comment: When we consider asymmetric pairings, then how can $t(P, Q)$ and $t(Q, P)$ exist at the same time? $P$ belongs to $G1$ and $Q$ belongs to $G2$ right?

Comment: Yes, the groups are switched in the definition of the (original) Ate pairing, i.e., the first element is in $G2$ and the second in $G1$. The Ate pairing also assumes that $P$ and $Q$ are in specific subgroups, so it is a little more specific than Tate, but this does not matter for the question at hand.